# How to deselect / select specific AutoFilter options consecutively using VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm trying to create a macro which will allow me to deselect / select specific Filter options, consecutively.

So in the below example, if I click "Deselect Type 1", then "Type 1" will be removed from the filter.

If I subsequently click "Deselect Type 2", then "Type 2" will be deselected from the Filter, but "Type 1" will also still be deselected.

If I click "Select Type 1", then "Type 1" will be reselected, and "Type 2" will remain deselected.

[image: example]

I've tried to use the record macro function however it doesn't work for subsequent deselects / selects. The way the record macro function works with AutoFilter is that it identifies the options that remain ticked and adds it to the array, which doesn't work with subsequent recordings for the other buttons. Here is the code for when you deselect Type 1 when recording, and as you can see it removes it from the array of options ticked.

```
'
' DeselectType1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$25").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Is there a way to code it so that it removes a specific option from the filter? And allows for subsequent options to be removed as I described above?

Comment: [This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161327/vba-code-to-deselect-particular-item-from-filter-or-swap-to-solve)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you ask is not so simple. You cannot record a macro for it, because the macro records only the final state of your settings and not the way you achieve it. Secondly, macro does not create variables to store the initial state of the filter.
Here you must first read the initial filter settings, then apply required changes.
Another problem is when reading filter settings their contents depends on the number of criteria. There are different for 1, 2 or 3+ criteria. Fortunately, when you set criteria, you can apply 1 model for many criteria and Excel internally converts it when there are less than 3.
Here is my proposal:

```
Sub Sel(item As String)
    Dim Crit1, Crit2, Oper As Long
    If Left(item, 1) <> "=" Then item = "=" & item
    ReadFilter Crit1, Crit2, Oper
    If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=item
    Else
       Select Case Oper
           Case 0, 1
               If Crit1 = item Then Exit Sub
               Crit1 = Array(Crit1, item)
               Oper = 7
           Case 2
               If Crit1 = item Or Crit2 = item Then Exit Sub
               Crit1 = Array(Crit1, Crit2, item)
               Oper = 7
           Case 7
               Dim d As Long
               d = UBound(Crit1)
               ReDim Preserve Crit1(d + 1)
               Crit1(d + 1) = item
        End Select
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Crit1, _
            Operator:=Oper, Criteria2:=Crit2
    End If
End Sub

Sub DeSel(item As String)
    Dim Crit1, Crit2, Oper As Long
    If Left(item, 1) <> "=" Then item = "=" & item
    ReadFilter Crit1, Crit2, Oper
    If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Oper
        Case 0
            If Crit1 = Empty Then
                Crit1 = Filter(AllItems, item, False)
                Oper = 7
            End If
        Case 1
            If Crit1 = item Then
                Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1
            End If
            Exit Sub
        Case 2
            If Crit1 <> item And Crit2 <> item Then Exit Sub
            If item = Crit1 Then Crit1 = Crit2
            Crit2 = Empty
        Case 7
            Crit1 = Filter(Crit1, item, False)
    End Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Crit1, _
        Operator:=Oper, Criteria2:=Crit2
End Sub

Private Sub ReadFilter(Crit1, Crit2, Oper As Long)
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        If Intersect(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1), _
            Selection.CurrentRegion.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
            ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
    End If
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(1).On Then
            On Error Resume Next
            With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(1)
                Crit1 = .Criteria1
                Oper = .Operator
                Crit2 = .Criteria2
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function AllItems()
    Dim rng As Range, arr
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1)
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)  'without header
    arr = rng.Parent.Evaluate(""" ="" & " & rng.Address)
    AllItems = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Function
```

Procedures to select or deselect items require arguments. When you assign macros to buttons you must provide this argument e.g. for Select Type 1 you should use:

```
'Sel "Type 1"'
```

for Deselect Type 2:

```
'DeSel "Type 2"'
```

The whole phrase must be surrounded by single quotes (due to arguments).
To make it work you must put cursor in a region of your data, autofiltering should be turned on and column where you apply the filter should be the first column in a filtering area.